# iCloud email account won't sync with Windows 11 Mail

Tags: email, icloud, windows-11, windows-mail

I had my iCloud account setup fine on Windows 10, and upgrading to Windows 11, it still functioned well.

However, I accidentally revoked my app-specific password from iCloud account setting(which I believe is required to setup iCloud account on Windows Mail, if two-factor authentication is turned on).

So I generated a new one, but new email still won't sync. I was able to login successfully, and I believe my Calendar was able to sync, but no emails are downloaded to my Windows Mail, nor I could sent email with my iCloud account from Windows Mail.

---

Things to note:

1. When adding an account, it will automatically change my account name to `(!idspnInternetMailICloudAccountName)` despite I have manually set it to other names.
2. Try to sync, sometime it doesn't show anything, sometimes it will shows error code `0x80070001`.
3. Windows Calendar works fine, I can sync without problem. Windows People doesn't work however, and also shows `0x80070001` when attempting to fix my account.
4. I have iCloud for Windows installed, but I believe it only work with Microsoft Outlook.
5. If needed, I'm using `22449.1000` OS build at the moment, and I have `22454.1000` downloaded, will upgrade it and see if the problem goes away.

---

Edit:

Seems like upgrading/restarting the machine without deleting the bad account first made it even worse. Now I can't delete that account anymore :D

Comment: I strongly suspect your issues are entirely based on the fact you are running a build from the Developer channel.  iCloud integration does indeed only work with Microsoft Outlook.  [However, it does appear that 0x80070001, is pretty generic of an error. It basically amounts to an HTTP/HTTPS error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121455/what-is-error-code-is-0x80070001-and-how-can-i-solve-it)

Comment: @Ramhound I bet you are right. Was unsure it was the dev build or mail/icloud server integration at first, but it went worse after upgrade/restart, so I bet it's the dev build.

Comment: You could try creating a new user and seeing if it's a credential issue.  You don't say if it worked before you revoked your application-specific password.

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe that would let me add an account in Mail, but it's unlikely to fix the old bad account (I can't delete it anymore after upgrade/restart). Reinstall Mail doesn't help either. I will probably check my registry, or just reroll to older backups.

Comment: It confirms if it’s a Windows 11 problem which cannot be thrown out, until you can confirm, it does work on Windows 11.  If it does work then I have some ideas.